# MVC how to hide value passed via ViewData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewdata

Wondering if anyone can help, I'm passing a value from a controller to view:

```
public ActionResult EmailResult(string result)
{
   ViewData["result"] = result;
   return View();
}
```

The value of result shows in the URL of the returned view, is it possible to hide that value? I know from a view to controller you make it a hidden input type but how do you do the same from controller to view?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Can you show how you are passing? Use POST method

Comment: The URL you're seeing is from the request going to your `EmailResult` method. Whatever your controller returns most definitely does not show up in the URL unless it's a redirect action.

Comment: Why don't you use a `model`? It's called MVC for a reason.

Comment: The url has nothing to do with anything you pass in the ViewData. Your problem is another, maybe you haven't read too much about MVC...

Comment: Covert EmailResult into HttpPost action.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume you have a form, then we can assume you're not using the post method of the form.  Try adding method="post" to your form tag.

As others point out, the problem is before you even get to this Controller Action - its on the page before.